# Elastic Beanstalk multi-container and php.ini

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using the Elastic Beanstalk multi-container environment. I've created my own lightweight PHP7 + nginx image (https://github.com/maestrooo/eb-docker-php7) which comes with some sane PHP.ini settings (https://github.com/maestrooo/eb-docker-php7/blob/master/config/custom.ini).

However, I'd like to turn off the "opcache.validate_timestamps" option. The problem is that if I do it in the custom.ini in the image, it will also be applied on development.

I therefore wanted to be able to set it to "off" through .ebextensions file (this way it will only be deployed on production, as `eb local run` command ignore .ebextensions files), so I added a .ebextensions/server.config file to something like that:

```
files:
  "/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/project.ini":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      opcache.validate_timestamps = off
```

While the file is properly added to the instance, unfortunately it is still to "On". It seems because PHP needs to be restarted, but I've been unable to know how I could restart PHP in the context of the Docker multi-container environment.

Did anyone were able to do something similar?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps a "container_commands" section might be able to restart php. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands